# Find and replace string and convert the matched string to number or currency

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, preg-replace, add-filter

How to find and replace string and convert the matched string to number or currency in the functions.php

content: "<div>[myprice=100]</div> <div>[myprice=1000]</div> <div>[myprice=5000]</div>"

I want replace to: "<div>$ 100.00</div> <div>$ 1,000.00</div> <div>$ 5,000.00</div>"

but the code below i get: "<div>100</div> <div>1000</div> <div>5000</div>"

```
function replace_myprice($content)
{
    $content = preg_replace('/\[myprice=([0-9^[]*)\]/', '\$ $1', $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_myprice');
```

Comment: Any issue with your code.?

Comment: I want replace to: "<div>$ 100.00</div> <div>$ 1,000.00</div> <div>$ 5,000.00</div>"

but the result: "<div>100</div> <div>1000</div> <div>5000</div>"